# Cannot find module '@google/maps'

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou a utilizar o pacote [`@google/maps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps), instalando:

```
npm install @google/maps
```

e

```
npm install @types/googlemaps
```

Efetuei a importação:

```
import * as gmaps from '@google/maps'
```

Porém recebo o erro

> Cannot find module '@google/maps'

Comment: acredito que essa documentação possa te ajudar https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encorajo fortemente que você use alguma biblioteca angular feita pra uso da api do maps, como a [angular-maps](https://angular-maps.com). Há muitos problemas relatados com os type definitivos criados até então, a documentação pobre é uma delas, em teoria com o `@type/google-maps` você nem precisaria do `import` e somente deveria usar uma variável padrão de acesso.